# Switching spring profile based on docker environment variable does not work

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

*docker-compose.yml:*

```
services:
  server:
    image: server:latest
    environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 18080:18080
```

*Dockerfile:*

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    SLEEP=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS="" \

RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh server
WORKDIR /home/server

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh && chown server:server entrypoint.sh
USER server

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
# expose server ports
EXPOSE 8080 18080

ADD *.jar server.jar
```

*entrypoint.sh:*

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "The application will start in ${SLEEP}s..." && sleep ${SLEEP}
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar "${HOME}/server.jar" "$@"
```

I have 3 application.yml: `application.yml`, `application-dev.yml` and `application-prod.yml` which differ from database address.

But when I run `docker-compose up`, the server always use the default setting even I mentionned as in *docker-compose.yml* that the active profile is dev.

I'd like to know how to enable different profile in docker-compose file.
Thanks.

**edit:**
the *server.jar* file is built using `assemble` of gradle.

Comment: If you echo the env var in the entry point does it show up?

Comment: No, I can't even boot my app since default configuration does not provide a database address, which throws exception during bootup.

Comment: Line 3 of entrypoint.sh before your java add $SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE to the output of the sh echo does if print?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a command: name space like below:

```
services:
  server:
    image: server:latest
    environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 18080:18080
    command: --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

After your container runs this will be appended to your entry point and spring boot will pickup this profile. It will be executed like :

Java -jar yourJar.jar --spring.profiles.active = prod.

And if you want to run your project app in various environment of your company and for various environment you have different kubernetes cluster configured then configure this setting differently on different kubernetes environment for your app . Means while running your docker image in qa environmner qa Kubernetes cluster will pass --spring.profiles.active = qa
and similarily staging and Prod cluster.

And even  if you you want to use environment variable you are using  then use

```
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS}
-Dspring.profiles.active={your envronment variable name describe in docker compose} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar "${HOME}/server.jar" "$@"
```

Check this on github:
https://github.com/vaneetkataria/MicroService_Architecture/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks. I copied the configurations from JHipster project, so I thought I can build the project without manually modifying the config files.

Comment: I tried to add `command: --spring.profiles.active=dev` in compose file, it says `Unrecognized option: --spring.profiles.active=dev` during startup. If I use only the environment `- SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev` in compose file, the spring log shows the correct profile name, but not the correct configuration. It still uses the default data base address in the `application.yml` file instead of `application-dev.yml`.

Comment: Did you changed your entrypoint.sh script to have -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE} before -Djava.security.edg ? When your conatiners entry point will execute it will pick this enviroment variable and its value will be passed in java -jar command as syatem property.

Comment: appending --spring.profiles.active=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE In your java -jar command present in entrypoint.sh will also do . As this will be paased as property on run time while running this boot app. Make sure your environment variable is properly set in docker container by issuing echo $SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE in docker container console .

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

.yaml files are handled differently than .properties files.

properties will look for a file with the active profile in the name:
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
...

yaml files, however you store all profiles in a single file separated by '---'.

Example [using your existing docker-compose.yaml]:

application.yaml:

```
spring:    
  application:    
    your-application-name
  [other global application settings]    
  ...   

---
spring:
    profiles: dev    
[other settings which apply only to dev environment]


---
spring:
    profiles: prod
[all production settings (will overwrite other values if present]
```

Comment: That's not true, you can separate your yaml files in the same convention as properties if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Darren.  I wasn't aware.  I wasn't able to get it to work for me so I went with the way I listed above and it worked.  I assumed that it was just how the yaml version worked.